# Omitting namespaces in swift

Tags: swift

I have an issue to omit namespaces in swift

```
struct Constant {
    static let loginAPI: String = "login"
    static let signUpAPI: String = "signup"
}

class Network {
    var api: String
    init(api: String) {
        self.api = api
    }
}

var network = Network(api: Constant.loginAPI)
```

Instead of using `Constant.loginAPI` I just want to use `.loginAPI`. 
How is it possible?

Comment: Show how the `init(api:)` method is declared.

Comment: And what happens if you simply use `.loginAPI`?

Comment: @rmaddy: I already updated the code, to shorten code :)

Comment: enum of strings instead of struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`enum`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) instead:

```
enum API: String {
    case login = "login"
    case signUp = "signup"
}

class Network {
    let api: API
    init(api: API) {
        self.api = api
    }
}

let network = Network(api: .login)
```

And, when `Network` needs the string value, it can use `api.rawValue`. Or, if you don’t really need those strings, you can simplify it further:

```
enum API {
    case login
    case signUp
}
```

---

While I think the above `enum` is the natural pattern when trying to specify one of a series of predetermined values, it’s worth noting that you can achieve something similar with `struct`:

```
struct API {
    let value: String

    static let login = API(value: "login")
    static let signUp = API(value: "signup")
}

class Network {
    var api: API
    init(api: API) {
        self.api = api
    }
}

let network = Network(api: .login)
```

And, in this case, `Network` can access `api.value` to retrieve the string value.

With this `struct` approach, though, there’s nothing to stop someone from doing something potentially invalid, such as:

```
extension API {
    static let foo = API(value: "bar")
}

let network = Network(api: .foo)
```

Or just doing it directly:

```
let network = Network(api: API(value: "baz"))
```

So, you’d only use this `struct` pattern if dynamically adding values might make sense. For example, when working with `NotificationCenter`, it’s nice to create your own `Notification.Name` static values because one might both post and observe one’s own custom notifications, but you can still use the convenient syntax.

All of that having been said, in this case, the enumeration is the natural solution.

Comment: @NhuNguyen Please don't forget to indicate that your question has been solved by clicking the checkmark to the left of the best answer. You haven't done so to any of your questions in a very long time.